# How to synchronise data with parse.com

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to list out all the active users currently using the app or have just opened the app, so how to update that list after a interval of time(say 2sec) so that the user list updates automatically and shows the current active users.
I am using parse server

Comment: Try to use timer.

Comment: I thought parse is dead

Comment: I am using parse on aws

Comment: I tried using timer but after sometime it produces an exception